# iOS Accessing UIScreen on Background Thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, grand-central-dispatch, retina

I have a method that is in charge of loading details about events (queries a sqlite database for titles, descriptions, thumbnail paths, etc.) that, since I need to call this for a large amount of events, I am dispatching to a background thread using Grand Central Dispatch.

The problem is I am getting a UIKit thread exception (letting me know I'm running UI methods on a thread other than the main thread, causing the app to crash). I'm not changing the UI at all so this was nearly impossible to find, but I finally narrowed it down to one line of code:

```
bool retina = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale > 1.0);
```

I am using UIScreen to determine if the device has a retina screen (to determine if the thumbnail image path should have "@2x" appended at the end) and just accessing this (what appears to be a static variable) throws that UIKit exception.

Is there a work-around for determining if the screen is retina that doesn't use UIKit (or is background-thread safe), or is there a better way to figure this out?

Note: I'm using Xamarin (C#) to create the app, but any answer in swift is perfectly fine and easy to convert.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the variable once on startup (i.e. main thread) and use it thereafter?

Comment: I thought of that, but the method is called in so many different places that it would require a lot of refactoring. Unless I setup a singleton that determined that on startup, but would that be overkill just to determine if the screen was retina? Or is that a good idea?

Comment: Re: "different places"  Do you have a specific object type for managing the data loading?  Is it initialized on the main thread? (Otherwise, I don't know the Xamarin architecture but in a "Xcode" app, I'd be tempted to make it a property of the application delegate -- not perfect but reasonable for a single variable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't have to specify `@2` when opening images you just display on screen. iOS selects the correct version with `UIImage(named: "BaseName")`.

But if you need to is here your Swift code:

```
func isRetina() -> Bool
{
    var scale: CGFloat = 0.0
    DispatchQueue.main.sync
    {
        scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }

    return scale > 1.0
}
```

Because you use it in many place, consider putting this in some utility/base class.

Comment: Completely forgot you could have blocking calls in Grand Central Dispatch. Perfect answer

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to also up the answer :-) (Or can't you do that with 100+ points?)